# Access history with pages created through render()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-router-native

I am attempting to implement a multi-language option in my React Native application. I'm using `react-router` to navigate the page. The approach I am attempting involves passing the current locale to the components as a prop.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {NativeRouter, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-native'

import WelcomePage from './components/WelcomePage'
import TestPage from './components/TestPage'

let lang = 'en'

const Main = () => {
 return (
 <NativeRouter>

    <Switch>
      
      <Route exact path="/" render ={() => <WelcomePage lang={lang}/>}/>            
      <Route exact path="/testpage" render{() => <TestPage lang={lang}/>}/>

    </Switch>

 </NativeRouter>
)
}

export default Main;
```

WelcomePage.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {Text, View, Button} from 'react-native' 



const WelcomePage = ({history, lang}) => {
return (
    <View>
        <View>

            <Text>Current language: {lang}</Text>   
            {// works so far}
        </View>

        <View>
            <Button title="Change view" onPress={() => history.push("/testpage")}/>
            {//crashes here, assumably because it doesn't get the history prop through the render() function}
        </View>
    </View>
  )
}


export default WelcomePage
```

This seems to work for the most part, but crashes on `history.push()`, with the error message

`undefined is not an object (evaluating 'history.push')`

From this it seems apparent to me that it is not possible to access the `history` prop in this scenario, but why is that? And how can I fix my issue? Perhaps my fundamental approach is flawed, in which case I would appreciate any suggestions for improvements. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to pass the history function as a prop from the parent ? like this:

```
const Main = () => {
 const history = {
   push: (route) => {
     ...use navigator to change page
   }
 }
 return (
 <NativeRouter>

    <Switch>
      
      <Route exact path="/" render ={() => <WelcomePage history={history} lang={lang}/>}/>            
      <Route exact path="/testpage" render{() => <TestPage lang={lang}/>}/>

    </Switch>

 </NativeRouter>
)
}

export default Main;
```